# MarkLogic search for documents containing polygons

Tags: marklogic

I am trying to write a query against a MarkLogic set of documents that contain geospatial information. Searching for the documents containing points was relatively easy, but I have some documents that define polygons.

```
<gml:Polygon gml:id="test" srsName="EPSG:4326">
  <gml:exterior>
    <gml:LinearRing>
      <gml:pos>0 5</gml:pos>
      <gml:pos>5 10</gml:pos>
      <gml:pos>10 5</gml:pos>
      <gml:pos>5 0</gml:pos>
      <gml:pos>0 5</gml:pos>
    </gml:LinearRing>
  </gml:exterior>
</gml:Polygon>
```

My problem is that I cannot find a cts: or gml: type of query that will allow a user to define a polygon to search for a polygon. I can compare polygons using (http://docs.marklogic.com/6.0/cts:polygon-intersects) type of functions, but that doesn't seem to allow me to query for polygons, just compare shape objects.

Any suggestion on how to do this (or confirmation that I cannot do this) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So you want to search for polygons having a particular set of vertices? Exact matches only? Would any match also use `gml:Polygon` in the same way?

Comment: I want to be able to search for a polygon using a polygon and give the user options to specify "intersect", "contains"... possibly "disjoint" (I don't see an API call for this but I'm assuming there is a way to do it). Polygon is just one example because I would like to be able to receive WKT and have that be used for the search parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error trying to create a query that worked as expected, I created a solution that worked for my situation. I had documents in MarkLogic that had a mix of `gml:Point` and `gml:Polygon` information. The problem I had was trying to get a query that covered both situations when the user enters any WKT query.

An example `gml:Point` would be:

```
<gml:Point srsDimension="2" srsName="http://somesite.com">
  <gml:pos>1 1</gml:pos>
</gml:Point>
```

Or it could be like the `gml:Polygon` described in the original question.

My mindset was that I needed to query the `gml:Polygon`, but in fact, I needed to query the `gml:LinearRing` using an [cts:element-child-geospatial-query](http://docs.marklogic.com/6.0/cts%3aelement-pair-geospatial-query?q=element-pair-geospatial-query) query.

My final query looked like (supports both gml and gml32):

```
cts:or-query((
  cts:element-child-geospatial-query(
    xs:QName("gml:Point"),
    xs:QName("gml:pos"),
    $parsedGeometry
  ), 
  cts:element-child-geospatial-query(
    xs:QName("gml32:Point"),
    xs:QName("gml32:pos"),
    $parsedGeometry
  ),
  cts:element-child-geospatial-query(
    xs:QName("gml:LinearRing"),
    xs:QName("gml:pos"),
    $parsedGeometry
  ), 
  cts:element-child-geospatial-query(
    xs:QName("gml32:LinearRing"),
    xs:QName("gml32:pos"),
    $parsedGeometry
  )
))
```

Then adding the proper geospatial element child indexes would make the query return what I expect and give sub 0.2 second responses.

Answer (score 2):

Create a `cts:polygon` and use it with [`cts:element-geospatial-query`](http://docs.marklogic.com/cts%3aelement-geospatial-query). The `$regions` parameter takes `cts:region*`, and `cts:polygon` is a subtype of `cts:region`. Once you have a `cts:element-geospatial-query` you can compose it with other `cts:query` items and use it with [`cts:search`](http://docs.marklogic.com/cts%3asearch) or [`search:resolve`](http://docs.marklogic.com/search%3aresolve).

```
cts:element-geospatial-query(
  xs:QName("gml:Polygon"),
  cts:polygon(10.0, 35.0, 20.0, 40.0))
```

Comment: This is definitely what I need, although testing my data is returning not enough results (from what I am assuming should happen). Going to play with this a bit more but I might have to create another question if I can't figure out how to get the results back I am expecting.

Comment: After a bunch of testing, this didn't actually work. The query was not returning all expected results within a very simple data set. See my answer for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You're close, but there are still cases where your search polygon can overlap the region in the database without covering one of the region's perimiter points.

MarkLogic Professional Services has a library that does the standard geo operations (intersects, disjoint, contains, within, overlaps, etc) over stored polygons, linestrings, boxes, circles, etc.  It works by using a pre-filter step that involves a combination of forward and reverse queries based on cts:bounding-boxes and additional decorating points, leveraging the MarkLogic geo indexes.  It then has a secondary step that performs fine-grained exact filter on the polygons/regions that survive the first filter, so you wind up with an exact set of matching regions.

It’s not publicly available, but you can contact your MarkLogic account manager if you want to bring in Professional Services to get access to the library.